# How to exclude a single number in while loops. (Begginer question)

Tags: python

I have a pretty simple task where i need to generate every integer below 15 that isn't 10.
I know that this is a pretty basic question but i don't know how to solve it.

```
i = 0
while i < 16 and i != 10:
    print(i)

i += 1
```

I tried this but it just loops 0 forever.
Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that your incrementing of `i` is not indented properly so the condition for ending the loop is never reached.

A for loop is probably easier to understand:

```py
for i in range(16):  # range(16) = [0,1, ... 14, 15]
    if i == 10:
        continue  # skip to next iteration
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use Python, you can code like this :

```
i = 0
while (i < 16):
  if i != 10:
     print(i)
  i = i + 1
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).